# Can router connect back to itself over Internet and why?

Tags: router, internet, lan, port-forwarding, wan

As it it sates in title.

Every router I had couldn't connect back to itself over Internet, for example:

1. I open forward port 22 for ssh on my PC.
2. I try to connect to that ssh with other PC in same network, with `ssh user@my.public.ip` but I get refused by router
3. I can connect from other network (other public IP) just fine, with same `ssh user@my.public.ip`

Is that just my bad luck with routers or there is something behind it?

Thanks

Comment: If your router doesn't support it, then a workaround is to use a DNS entry for external that you replicate in your `hosts` file or internal DNS.  So externally it resolves to the public address and internally resolves to the internal address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need a router that supports loop back functionality.

> Many DSL routers/modems prevent loopback connections as a security feature. This means that a machine on your local network (e.g. behind your DSL router/modem) cannot connect to a forward facing IP address (such as 199.149.252.44) of a machine that it also on your local network. Connecting to the local IP address (such as 192.168.2.40) of that same machine works fine.

Source: http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers

This thread over at sec discusses security implications (or lack thereof):
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem

Comment: Or a router that supports being reflashed with linux/bsd firmware.  Linux can do lookback fine.

Comment: What are the adverse security implications of a NAT loopback router?

Comment: @Ярослав Рахматуллин : I've added a security link to my answer